# How set the base path of rest api with webpack

Tags: rest, build, webpack

We have developed a component with React and using webpack to create a debploy package. The component talks to an API endpoint. There are different endpoints for development, test and production. How/Where to we set the base path during the build?

Answer (score 3):

One of possible solutions:

1) Pass env to webpack (example is valid for windows):

```
set "ENV=production" && webpack --progress --colors
```

2) Define with [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) ENV variable in your app (or you can simply define endpoint here):

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENV)
})
```

3) Then require js-file with env parameters in your app:

```
let envParams = require('environments/' + ENV);
```

assuming you have `environments` folder with `production.js`, `development.js` and `test.js` files with params:

```
export default {
    apiEndpoint: '...',
    // other params
};
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you!  Quick note - using `export default {...}` with `require('...')` yields a `default` key, e.g. `envParams.default`.  Not sure if this was intentional.  My preference is no `default` key, so my small modification was `module.exports = {...}` instead of `export default {...}`.